# Spec rpm: I want make gmake -j3

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

On my .spec file I want to pass `alias make=gmake -j3`, using a bash script I did

```
alias make="gmake -j3"
```

how to do in a .spec file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do **not** want to add `-j3`. That is settings just for your machine. You want to add something that will work everywhere:

```
gmake %{?_smp_mflags}
```

This macro is by default set to:

```
%_smp_mflags %( \
    [ -z "$RPM_BUILD_NCPUS" ] \\\
        && RPM_BUILD_NCPUS="`/usr/bin/getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`"; \\\
    if [ "$RPM_BUILD_NCPUS" -gt 16 ]; then \\\
        echo "-j16"; \\\
    elif [ "$RPM_BUILD_NCPUS" -gt 3 ]; then \\\
        echo "-j$RPM_BUILD_NCPUS"; \\\
    else \\\
        echo "-j3"; \\\
    fi )
```

I.e. more or less to number of your CPUs. On your machine it can be 3. On my machine it is 8.

See
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Parallel_make

Answer (score 0):

Solution found using variables

on top of spec

```
%define installc /opt/freeware/bin/install
%define make /opt/freeware/bin/gmake
```

on build and install part

```
%build
%{make} -j3
%install
%{installc} -m644 yasql.conf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_sysconfdir}/yasql.conf
```